# Internet Explorer: Ignore unknown ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6

To fix a bug that only occurs in Firefox, I need to use the `loaded` Promise of a `FontFace`. I currently use the following code for that:

```js
if (document.fonts) {
    for (var fontFace of document.fonts.values()) {
        if (fontFace['family'] == fontFamily) {
            fontFace.loaded.then(doStuff);
        }
    }
} else {
    doStuff();
}
```

This works and only targets the browsers that support the font loading API. But because of the `for .. of`, Internet Explorer logs an error and stops the JS execution. Putting the code in a `try .. catch` block doesn't work, ignoring the error via `window.onerror` would probably work, but is quite hacky.

Is there a way to iterate over `document.fonts.values` that is also supported by IE or do you know a better way to use the `loaded` Promise in browsers that support it?

Comment: Use a different loop and it should work.

Comment: What do you mean with different loop? `document.fonts.values` returns an iterator, iterating with `for .. in` or with a "normal" for loop doesn't work.

Comment: _"Is there a way to iterate over document.fonts.values that is also supported by IE"_ No, because there is no `document.fonts` in IE in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear in the description. I'm aware that IE doesn't support the font loading API, but I wanted a way to iterate over `document.fonts.values` in supported browser without IE throwing an error. But I found a way in the meantime (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend

```
const fontFace = Array.from(document.fonts).find(face => face.family === fontFamily);
if (fontFace) {
  fontFace.loaded.then(doStuff);
}
```

`Array.from` creates an array from an iterable, and then you can use the normal `Array.prototype.some` to check for matches.

You could then simplify your whole check to

```
const fontFace = document.fonts &&
  Array.from(document.fonts).find(face => face.family === fontFamily);

if (fontFace) fontFace.loaded.then(doStuff);
else doStuff();
```

assuming you want to run `doStuff` if not of the font faces match either.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work because a `FontFaceSet` isn't array-like (has no `length` attribute) and therefore can't be converted to an array using `Array.from`.

Comment: It is not array-like, but it is iterable, so it will work with `Array.from`.

Comment: `Array.from(document.fonts)` returns an empty array (in Firefox and Chrome).

Comment: And does `for (var fontFace of document.fonts.values()) console.log(fontFace);` log anything? Or check `Array.from(document.fonts.values())`. If not, then they are just equal. Anything you can pass to `for..of`, you can pass to `Array.from` to get all the items out.

Comment: Sorry, didn't check that. It doesn't log anything, as well. The code works and is more elegant than my implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't use `for-of` iteration in your code, when it is supposed to run in an unsupported browser. The thing is that error occurs at the moment of parsing code before your condition will be executed and checked.

If you really want to use for-of, you will need to create a special JS-bundle for modern browsers or process your code with Babel to convert your code to es5-compatible.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem by using `next()` in a `do .. while` loop (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with the following code:

```js
if (document.fonts) {
     var iter = document.fonts.values();
     do {
         var item = iter.next();
         var fontFace = item.value;
         if (fontFace && fontFace['family'] == fontFamilyStr) {
             fontFace.loaded.then(doStuff);
         }
     } while (!item.done);
} else {
            doStuff();
}
```

IE doesn't log an error anymore and the code works in Firefox / Chrome.